# Inconsistency with as.difftime

Tags: r

I can convert strings containing hour, minute or second specifications to a `difftime`:

```
> as.difftime("12 h", "%H")
Time difference of 12 hours
> as.difftime("12 m", "%M")
Time difference of 12 mins
> as.difftime("12 s", "%S")
Time difference of 12 secs
```

But I can't do so with a week specification, because there is no appropriate format …, although `"weeks"` is a legitimate *unit* of `difftime`:

```
> as.difftime("12 w", "%…")
```

Am I overlooking something?

Comment: It doesn't work beyond hours. Why should be obvious, if you study the code. The relevant part is `difftime(strptime(tim, format = format), strptime("0:0:0", 
            format = "%X"), units = units)`. If you specify only a time for `strptime` it adds the current date. If you only specify part of a date it does some surprising things, in particular for weeks.

Comment: @Roland - It didn't come to my mind how easily I can _study the code_. If you put your comment into an answer, I could accept it.

Comment: Actually, I think you should bring this to the attention of the R-devel mailing list. I'd consider this at least a documentation issue. But possibly R-core could even fix it.

Comment: @Roland - Okay, I'll do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Roland noted:

> It doesn't work beyond hours. … obvious, if you study the code. The relevant part is
>
> ```
> difftime(strptime(tim, format = format), strptime("0:0:0", format = "%X"), units = units)
> ```
>
> . If you specify only a time for `strptime` it adds the current date.

Indeed it is easy to *study the code* in the **R Console**:

```
> as.difftime
function (tim, format = "%X", units = "auto") 
{
    if (inherits(tim, "difftime")) 
        return(tim)
    if (is.character(tim)) {
        difftime(strptime(tim, format = format), strptime("0:0:0", 
            format = "%X"), units = units)
    }
    else {
        if (!is.numeric(tim)) 
            stop("'tim' is not character or numeric")
        if (units == "auto") 
            stop("need explicit units for numeric conversion")
        if (!(units %in% c("secs", "mins", "hours", "days", "weeks"))) 
            stop("invalid units specified")
        .difftime(tim, units = units)
    }
}
```

The crux of the matter is that the use of `strptime` causes a *time interval* character string given to `as.difftime` to be treated as a *point in time*, from which 0 h of the 
*current* day is subtracted. This for various reasons makes `as.difftime` with a string unusable for days and weeks, for example a value of 0  days is not accepted by `strptime`, although it were perfectly valid as an interval.

A request for comments on the R-devel mailing list didn't elicit wide response. (I received some valuable thoughts from Emil Bode by private mail, thus I won't reproduce them here.) So, I'll refrain from proposing a change to `as.difftime`, also because changing it would introduce discrepances between R versions.